# Powershell/Batch Files: Verify that a file contains at least one entry from a list of strings

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Here is my current issue: I have a list of 1800 customer numbers (ie 123456789). I need to determine which of these numbers show up in another, much larger (4 gb) file. The larger file is a fixed-width file of all customer information. I know how I would do this in SQL, but like I said it's a flat file.

When searching for individual numbers, I was using a command I found elsewhere on this site which worked very well:

```
get-content CUSTOMERINFO.txt -ReadCount 1000 | foreach { $_ -match "123456789" }
```

However, I do not have the expertise to translate this into another command, or a batch file, which would load list.txt and search all lines in customerinfo.txt for the requisite strings.

Time is not a major constraint, as this is running on a test server and will be a once-off project.

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Comment: for a batch-file you can use `findstr` and loop over the inputs. `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%infile%) do (findstr %%a < %targetfile%)`

Comment: What kind of results are you looking for? Just to know if one of the IDs is there or about every id in every file that matches? DO you care about multiple matches? Have you tried _anything_ to fix this? I realize that you are not apt with PowerShell but this looks like a code writing request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `match` comparator can work over multiple values, you can separate them with a bar | character.

e.g.
`get-content CUSTOMERINFO.txt -ReadCount 1000 | foreach { $_ -match "DEF|YZ" }`

You can also read the contents of a file and replace newlines with a character of your choice.  So if list.txt is a list of values to search, such as

`DEF
 XY`

Then you can read it and convert it to a bar-separated list using the join operator:

`(Get-Content list.txt) -join "|"`

Put them together and you should have your solution:

```
$listSearch = (Get-Content list.txt) -join "|";
get-content CUSTOMERINFO.txt -ReadCount 1000 | foreach { $_ -match $listSearch}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I merely sent the output to a file using Out-File and then checked the total lines in the resultant file.

Comment: How does that work at all? `Get-Content xyz | foreach { $_ - match 'pattern' }` will output like `True True False False False`, not lines from the file, even if they do match the regex, won't it? You'd need it to be a `where` to filter the lines.

Comment: You're right. I ended up generating a large file and I believed that it was my results. I ended up writing my own code, which I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

So I appreciate everyone's help. Everybody gave me helpful info that let me get to my final solution, so I appreciate it. Especially to the guy who asked if this was a codewriting request, because it made me realize I needed to just write some code.

For anyone else who runs into the same problem, here is the code I ended up using:

```
$matches = Get-Content .\list.txt
foreach ($entry in $matches)
{ $results = get-content FiletoSearch -ReadCount 1000 | foreach { $_ -match $entry }
    if ($results -eq $null) { 
    $entry }
    else {
    "found"}
    }
```

This gives a 'found' entry for everything that was found (which is information I don't need), and gives back the value searched for when it's not found (which is information I do need).